# Función que recibe un argumento, si la entrada es nula retornar un valor nulo

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-13

A ver si me pueden ayudar con este ejercicio:

Cree una función llamada *n_clients* que dado un identificador de un
representante de ventas nos devuelva el número de clientes que tiene asignados. Si
la entrada es nula se debe devolver un valor nulo.

He llegado hast aqui: Teniendo en cuenta que num_empl es de tipo INT.

```
CREATE FUNCTION n_clients(num_empl anyelement) RETURNS anyelement AS $$
     SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM clients 
      WHERE rep_clie = $1
      GROUP BY rep_clie;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

He probado con anyelement pero cuando no ingreso un valor, me da error por el tipo de arg. No he puesto las tablas por que entiendo que el problema estaria mas en como declaro la función, o no es asi?

Muchas Gracias.

El error que me da:

```
select n_clients();
ERROR:  function n_clients() does not exist
LINE 1: select n_clients();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: @padaleiana Hecho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder llamar a la función sin el parámetro debes especificar un valor por defecto para el mismo cuando declaras la función. Sino la otra opción es llamar a la función con el valor NULL explícito `SELECT n_clients(NULL)`.

Para que la query retorne `NULL` cuando el parámetro es `NULL` utilicé la expresión `CASE` (sino retornaría el valor 0).

```
CREATE FUNCTION n_clients (num_empl int DEFAULT NULL) RETURNS int AS 
$$
    SELECT CASE WHEN num_empl IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(*) END
    FROM clients 
    WHERE rep_clie = num_empl
    GROUP BY rep_clie;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Gracias, por la respuesta.

Comment: De nada @BrunoRodriguez!!!